# How to use Machine Learning Algorithm to predict most discussed tweeter category

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk, multilabel-classification

INPUT I HAVE

I have a csv file which contains 2000 sentences as below:

WHAT I WANT TO DO

I want to:

A) Categorize each sentence

One way I am thinking is to create a dictionary where I will put each category related words
But I don't like this idea of creating dictionary , rather want machine to determine/predict itself.

Is there a better way of achieving this? 
How can I use Machine Learning here ?

Can you suggest Step by Step Process/Code/ML algorithm which can be trained?
I have experience on Python language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not necessarily a good application for machine learning. Essentially you're analyzing each word in a tweet and seeing if that word belongs in a predefined category. Machine learning might be used for something like sentiment analysis, where it can "learn" that individual words or groups of words convey a certain feeling, but to classify individual words doesn't really make sense. You would be trying to "train" a model to learn definitions of words.

I think your approach with the dictionary is viable, and much easier to accomplish. For each category you care about, add a few words and then you can use a [thesaurus API](https://words.bighugelabs.com/api.php) to programmatically find synonyms for each word in the category to expand the vocabulary of your dictionary.